# Access to host-named site collection in one Web Application

Tags: configuration, host-header, dns

I've created host-named site collection in a Web application by using the following PowerShell:

```
$dbName = "Content_Testing"
$aPool = "WebAppPool"
$waName = "Web Application Testing"
$web = New-SPWebbApplication -DatabaseName $dbName -ApplicationPool $aPool -Name $waName -Port 80

$web = Get-SPWebApplication $waName

New-SPSite -url "http://hostA.abc.com" -HostHeaderWebApplication $w -Name "HostA" -OwnerAlias "abc\thuan" -Template sts#0
```

After created, the URL "http://hostA.abc.com" can't be founded. Do I have to configure in DNS before accessing to "http://hostA.abc.com.

Regards,

T.s

Answer (score 1):

Yes before you try to access http://hostA.abc.com through anything but the object model you have to add the DNS entry (or modify the hosts file)

Creating the site only changed the IIS site for the WebApplication to listen to any request on port 80 not caught by any other IIS site, but for the traffic to reach this server you have to set up DNS.